# Blazor/C# Update One SQL Table Field on Button Click

Tags: c#, blazor

I have a details page in Blazor that shows a full record (from SQL view).

I have a button at the top of the page, and I would like to simply update one field (Status) on that existing record, and save it.

Being relatively new to this, and not a trained coder, I seem to be struggling.  It keeps trying to save a new record, rather than update the current.

Details Page Button:

```
<RadzenButton Button Text="Mark as Received" Click=@(args => MarkReceived(carPK))  ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Primary" ></RadzenButton>
```

Details Page Code

```
[Parameter]      
public Guid carPK {get; set;}

// WIR40
protected WIR40 WIR40Entity = new WIR40();
WIR40Repository wir40Repository = new WIR40Repository();


protected void MarkReceived(Guid Pk)
{
//Not sure if I need to first grab the record to update, Pk = Id of record
wir40Repository.GetByID(Pk)
WIR40Entity.Status = 3; //updates status from 1 to 3.
wir40Repository.Save();
StateHasChanged();
}
```

Runnig the code as is, I placed a few break points to see what is happening.  The correct PK is coming back, but it's actually creating a new record rather than trying to update the existing one(Shows all fields as null except Status).  What am I missing ?

Comment: Trying to follow along, are you utilizing Entity and `wir40Repository` is you context? If so try utilizing savechanges() instead of save. For further reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.savechanges?view=efcore-7.0

Comment: The Context lists the Table (WIR40).  WIR40Repository is the repository that handles the GetByID function.  wir40Repository is an instance of the Repository.